# How to use Objects in Windows Forms C++

Tags: c++, windows, forms, events, object

I have a windows forms program with a "Connect" and a "Disconnect" button.

When the Connect-Button is clicked an object of my own class should be created:

```
private: System::Void Connect_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
  my_class new_object();
  return;
}
```

After the Connect Button was clicked, the Disconnect-Button becomes enabled and the object should be deleted:

```
private: System::Void Disconnect_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             //delete new_object
             return;
         }
```

The problem is, i do not really know how i can delete my objekt from another method. How can i deliver the new_object to the Disconnect method?

Comment: Your object is deleted by the default destructor at the end of your event handler. In order to have acces from several event handlers to your variable you have to make it global.

Comment: Ok, so is there a way to create the object without it being deleted at the end of the event handle?
It should be created when the Connect button is clicked. Then there would be a Send button, which would call some methods of the object and in the end, it should be deleted when the disconnect button is clicked.

Comment: Make it global. Also as said above if you want to acces it from several handlers, it has to be global.

Comment: Sorry, i totally overlooked that!

Comment: Don't make it global, that's evil.  Make it a member of your form class.  You will need to ensure it is deleted even if the user never clicked the Disconnect button.  Use the FormClosed event for example.  Reading a book about Winforms programming is highly recommended btw, pay a visit to your local library.  You'll learn what destructors and finalizers do, things you need to know to write this kind of code properly.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to acces any variable from multiple handlers you have to make those variables global.

Also the objects are deleted using a [destructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_%28computer_programming%29) and not `delete` operators.

Also it is a bad habit explicitly calling the destructor. In your case if you will call it the program, it will crash as at the end of the execution the compiler will call on it's own the destructors for all the objects again and try to free the freed allready by you memory.